# Uploading an array of text to Parse

Tags: arrays, database, parse-platform, upload

I am creating a mail system where user A sends a piece of text to user B, user B stores the text in an array in a column called Inbox (which has the attribute array).

I create 5 users, the first 2 users responds with "POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/fjT08jUUk8 400 (Bad Request)"

HOWEVER, the last 3 users works perfectly fine. I'm really frustrated because I just can't figure out what the problem is. All the users are created with the same conditions.

I'll link the code used here:

```
<textarea name="msg" id="msg" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
<button ng-click="sendMessage(fetched_user.id)">Send</button>
(fetched_user.id is the corresponding id for the user you're targeting, double checked it)


$scope.sendMessage = function(UID) {     
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.equalTo('objectId', UID);
    query.first({
      success: function(object) {
        var text = $('#msg').val();
        object.add("Inbox", text );
        object.save();
        $scope.$apply();    
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
}
```

As always I'm really greatful for any kind of answer!! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it is php related, it was as suggested tag.. I'll remove it if it makes u feel better